# python library for splitting video

Tags: python, video

I need to split big video file into smaller pieces by time. Give me your suggestions, please, and if you can some tips for library usage. Thanks.

Comment: In what format is your video?

Comment: The main goal is to upload video to youtube. This determines formats

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) has [Python wrappers](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html).

As you're interested in video IO, have a look at [QueryFrame](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) and its related functions there.

In the end, your code will look something like this (completely untested):

```
import cv

capture = cv.CaptureFromFile(filename)
while Condition1:
    # Need a frame to get the output video dimensions
    frame = cv.RetrieveFrame(capture) # Will return None if there are no frames
    # New video file
    video_out = cv.CreateVideoWriter(output_filenameX,
        CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), capture.fps, frame.size(), 1)
    # Write the frames
    cv.WriteFrame(video_out, frame)
    while Condition2:
        # Will return None if there are no frames
        frame = cv.RetrieveFrame(capture)
        cv.WriteFrame(video_out, frame)
```

By the way, there are also ways to do this [without writing any code](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/1/ffmpeg).

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be what I want.

Comment: No problem.  In general, comments like "thanks, this is what I need" are better made by accepting the answer (click the tick symbol).  Glad you could get this worked out.  Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. I've been looking for a simple and clear library and code example for building a video and this was perfect. Thanks!

Comment: It does not work for me, raises error. First: `GrabFrame` returns an int (always 1 for me) and it is not applicable to `WriteFrame` because it needs `IplImage`. So i changed it to `QueryFrame` according to the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=createvideowriter#queryframe). Now it runs without errors, but the generated video has zero length, unreadable by any players.

Comment: @Lepi: you're right.  It should be `GrabFrame` followed by `QueryFrame` (if `GrabFrame` returns 1) or simply `RetrieveFrame` (which will return `None` if there is no frame available).  `QueryFrame` by itself may not be enough.  I've corrected the answer.  As far as your video having zero length, it's more likely to be a problem with your local install of OpenCV (it needs proper ffmpeg support to write video) than a problem with the above source.  You may want to try other codecs (other than MJPG) when creating the `VideoWriter` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Check [youtube-upload](http://code.google.com/p/youtube-upload), it splits the videos using ffmpeg.

> Youtube-upload is a command-line
>   script that uploads videos to Youtube.
>   If a video does not comply with
>   Youtube limitations (<2Gb and <15'),
>   it will be automatically splitted
>   before uploading. Youtube-upload
>   should work on any platform
>   (GNU/Linux, BSD, OS X, Windows, ...)
>   that runs Python and FFmpeg.